# System.Net.Web Exception in WCF server

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, iis, w3wp

I am getting the following exception thrown while trying to send all files of a folder to server and then get the processed output the C# console client..

Following is the exception,

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a
receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport 
connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SоcketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
аt System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

How ever if I process the same file as individual file it is working fine.

Following are the parameters of binding used,

**In server's web.config :**

```
<binding name="ExtendedMaxSize" 
               openTimeout="10:01:00" 
               receiveTimeout="10:10:00" 
               sendTimeout="10:01:00"
               maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
               maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
               messageEncoding="Text" 
               textEncoding="utf-8">
   <readerQuotas maxDepth="64"
                 maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                 maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                 maxBytesPerRead="8192"
                 maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
   <security mode="None">
     <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
   </security>
```

**In client's app.config:**

```
<binding name="WSHttpBinding_InterfaceWCFServer1"
         openTimeout="10:01:00" 
         receiveTimeout="10:10:00" 
         sendTimeout="10:01:00"
         bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
         transactionFlow="false"
         hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
         maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
         messageEncoding="Text"
         textEncoding="utf-8" 
         useDefaultWebProxy="true" 
         allowCookies="false">
 <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" 
               maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
               maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
               maxBytesPerRead="8192" 
               maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
 <security mode="None">
   <transport clientCredentialType="None" 
              proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="">
     <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
   </transport>
   <message clientCredentialType="Windows" 
            negotiateServiceCredential="true"
            algorithmSuite="Default" 
            establishSecurityContext="true" />
  </security>
</binding>
```

I am using 8 GB RAM in my laptop, both the server and clients are in the same machine.

On seeing the `Processes` in task manager I have found that w3wp.exe's usage is ranging from 700 MB to 6 GB, When ever the usage reaches limit of 95% I am getting this exception thrown and the memory used by `w3wp.exe` gets reduced to 700 mb or so then again it increases for each request until it reaches somewhere around 95 % of memory. So at this point am getting this exception thrown.

Comment: Next time format your question properly !

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your WCF server stores all data in memory so that you eventually exhaust available memory. This causes an OOM exception to be thrown in the server, potentially killing the process. This kills the TCP connection.

Rework your server design such that it does not need unbounded amounts of memory.

Comment: Where to change the maximum limit ?

Comment: At your local hardware store. Buy more RAM. Or, read my answer.